# Move specific file from all subdirectories and rename based on subdirectory

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a folder structure in a directory which is something like:

```
/ 
A, B/Subdir Level 1/ Subdir L2/Folder A/abc.json
A, C/Subdir Level 1/ Subdir L2/Folder A/abc.json
A, D/Subdir Level 1/ Subdir L2/Folder A/abc.json 
A, F/Subdir Level 1/ Subdir L2/Folder A/abc.json 
A, G/Subdir Level 1/ Subdir L2/Folder A/abc.json 
B, Z/Subdir Level 1/ Subdir L2/Folder A/abc.json 
C, F/Subdir Level 1/ Subdir L2/Folder A/abc.json
```

I want to copy all the abc.json files and put them in one New_Folder folder but rename them in the process so that I know where each abc.json came from.

```
New_Folder/ 
A, B_abc.json (or A, Babc.json...don't really care as long as A, B appear) 
A, C_abc.json 
A, D_abc.json
```

..... and so on

How can I achieve this with a shell script. I use Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming that you have already `cd` into the level that you want to keep in the name. You can double-check using `find`:

```
find -type f -iname abc.json
./A, B/Subdir Level 1/Subdir L2/abc.json
./A, C/Subdir Level 1/Subdir L2/abc.json
./A, F/Subdir Level 1/Subdir L2/abc.json
```

Assuming you have made the folder ../NewFolder already, the following command should copy all json files and put the 1st level subdirectory in the new name. Just make sure to paste all of the 4 lines into your terminal at once!

```
find -type f -iname \*.json | while read x; do
 dirname="$(echo "$x" | sed -r 's_^\.?/?__;s_/.*__')";
filename="$(echo "$x" | sed -r 's_.*/__')";
cp -v "$x" "../NewFolder/$dirname - $filename"; done

‘./A, B/Subdir Level 1/Subdir L2/abc.json’ -> ‘../NewFolder/A, B - abc.json’
‘./A, C/Subdir Level 1/Subdir L2/abc.json’ -> ‘../NewFolder/A, C - abc.json’
‘./A, F/Subdir Level 1/Subdir L2/abc.json’ -> ‘../NewFolder/A, F - abc.json’
```